# Python: Compare elements of a list at substring level

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I'm trying to compare two or more strings in a list. Input, what's been tried, output received using the method tried against what's been expected.

**Input:**

```
lis = [
'concat(tb1.col1, tb1.col2, tb1.col3) as alias1, tb1.col4, case when tb2.col2>1 then 1 else 0', 
'concat(tb1.col1, tb1.col2, tb1.col3) as alias1, concat(tb2.col1, tb2.col2, tb2.col3) as alias2, case when tb1.col1>1 then 1 else 0, tb3.col1'
]
```

**What's tried:**

```
for c in range(len(lis)-1):
    print(list(set(lis[c+1].split(', ')) - set(lis[c].split(', '))))
```

**Output received:**

```
['tb3.col1', 'tb2.col2', 
'concat(tb2.col1', 'tb2.col3) as alias2', 
'case when tb1.col1>1 then 1 else 0 end as alias4']
```

**Output expected:**

```
['concat(tb1.col1, tb1.col2, tb1.col3) as alias1', 
'tb1.col4', 'case when tb2.col2>1 then 1 else 0 end as alias3',
'concat(tb2.col1, tb2.col2, tb2.col3) as alias2', 
'case when tb1.col1>1 then 1 else 0 end as alias4', 
'tb3.col1']
```

Please help me!

Comment: Are you just trying to split elements in the list on comma?

Comment: no, it's not that simple. Splitting based on comma would further split ```concat(tb1.col1, tb1.col2, tb1.col3) as alias1``` whereas we need this as one element.